# Query not running in SQL*Plus

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I have the following code that runs perfectly fine in SQL Developer and it finishes within 1 minute of total run time:

```
SET TERM ON
SET ECHO ON
DECLARE
    max_date date;
    max_id number;
BEGIN
    select max(LOG_ID) into max_id from RUN_LOG;
    select max(TRAN_DT) into max_date from DATA_TX;
    insert into RUN_LOG 
    values(
        max_id + 1        /* Log ID */
        ,1                /* Chain ID */
        ,1                /* Job ID */
        ,sysdate          /* Start Time-stamp */
        ,sysdate          /* End Time-stamp */
        ,1                /* Run Result */
        ,max_date         /* Processing Date */
    );
    COMMIT;
END;
/
```

When I put this into a .SQL file and execute in SQL*Plus it never finishes.

Batch call is as follows:

```
sqlplus user/password@database @set_date.sql
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you terminate the last line of your SQL-file with `LF` character?

Comment: Can you run it interactively with sql plus?

Comment: You don't appear to have the `-s` flag, but do you maybe have `set feedback off` in you `login.sql`? Or are you just waiting for it to come back to a command prompt - which won't happen without an `exit` in the file. Might you have an uncommitted insert in SQL Developer? (Is thee a reason you aren't using a sequence for the log ID?)

Comment: You need to determine what the session is waiting for. Maybe it's waiting on a lock. By the way, querying MAX(ID) in order to set a unique column is very probably a bad idea due to concurrency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some kind of error in my Oracle session that caused my .sql to not return control back to my .bat file

Anyway, I also modified the call as follows:

exit | sqlplus -S user/password@database @set_date.sql

All is fine now.